# MATLAB kmeans not working for SURF/BRISK Points vectors

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, k-means, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

**Background Information**
I'm trying to apply Bag of Words on SURF/BRISK features as an experiment on the Cats/Dogs dataset. I've extracted all the features into a vector.

**Issue:**
When I feed the vectors into kmeans(points, numPts*0.04) it says that:

> Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'BRISKPoints'

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `BRISKPoints` is a MATLAB object, not a numeric matrix. You cannot do k-means on it directly.  What should go into k-means is the output of `extractFeatures`.  Note that `extractFeatures` can return either SURF or FREAK descriptors depending on the type of the input points or the value of the `'Method'` parameter.  You can use k-means to cluster SURF descriptors, which are simply numerical vectors, but not FREAK descriptors, which are strings of bits encapsulated in a `binaryFeatures` object.

By the way, as of R2014b there is built-in support for the bag of words image classification in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  Please see this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out when I need it again :)